# EF core many to many with joining table Get data

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a many-to-many relationship in EF core. I would like to retrieve all the users and roles assigned to them where UserRoles is active (IsActive)

I have three tables `User`, `Role`, `UserRoles` (see below).

According to business requirements, the user can exist without a role. Moreover, the role can exist without a user.

`IsActive` field in the `RoleUsers` table determines role is assigned to the user or not. `IsActive` is also used for soft delete.

Below is my linq query

```cs
 **return await _context.User
                .Include( c=> c.Role)
                .ThenInclude(e=> e.UserRoles.Where(u=> u.IsActive)))
                .ToListAsync<User>();**
```

SQL Server query would be something like below

```cs
public class User 
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public List<UserRoles > UserRoles  { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public Guid RoleId{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<UserRoles > UserRoles  { get; set; }
}

public class UserRoles 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid RoleId{ get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Role Role{ get; set; }
    public bool IsActive{ get; set; }

}
```

```cs
public DbSet<Role> Role{ get; set; }
public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
public DbSet<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
    
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
       .HasMany(m => m.Roles)
       .WithMany(g => g.Users)
       .UsingEntity<UserRoles>(
           mg => mg.HasOne(prop => prop.Role)
                   .WithMany(p => p.UserRoles)
                   .HasForeignKey(prop => prop.RoleId),
           mg => mg.HasOne(prop => prop.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.UserRoles)
                   .HasForeignKey(prop => prop.UserId),
           mg =>
           {
               mg.HasKey(prop => new { prop.RoleId, prop.UserId });
               mg.Property(prop => prop.CreatedOn).HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");
           }
       );

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Could you add into question which query generated by EF Core?

Comment: Looks like all you need is `.ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role)`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I have tried thenInclude (see below) still role coming empty 
var users = await _context.User
                .Include(e => e.UserRoles.Where(u => u.IsActive))
                .ThenInclude(s => s.Role)
                .Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize)
                .Take(filter.PageSize)
                .OrderBy(o => o.UserId)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync<User>();

Comment: If it runs without exceptions (does it?) then I wonder why `Role` is still "comping empty". Look at the generated SQL.

Comment: Hi @Ali, it seems you do not share UserEntitlements and Entitlement class. Also, it seems your shared linq and sql are quite different.

Comment: Hi, I am getting data when I remove **AsNoTracking()** below is the final script

       ` _context.User.Where(t => t.IsActive)
                       .Include(s => s.UserRoles.Where(o => o.IsActive))
                       .ThenInclude(e => e.Role)
                       .Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize)
                       .Take(filter.PageSize)              
                       .ToListAsync<User>();`

May I know how can I use AsNoTracking with include and thenInclude

Comment: Try  `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()`

Comment: Hi Danyliv,

It's working fine. Thanks. But can this improve the performance?

Comment: Additionally add `AsSplitQuery`.